# iOS PDFKit Swift 4 , How can I make text being typed in a PDFKIT text field widget be all caps?

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

I am using PDFKit to manipulate an existing PDF in an iOS mobile app. I can loop through all the annotations in a PDF, but I also want to set all textfields to have caps lock on by default. So that when the user selects the text field they are able to start typing in all caps by default.

Here's part of the code:

```
 func setAnnotationValues(_ annotations: [PDFAnnotation]){
    for annotation in annotations {

        annotation.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 8)
        if(annotation.widgetFieldType == .text) {
            //Want to do something here to set the text to be all caps
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not a UITextField it is an annotation in a PDF document using Apple's PDFKit library

Comment: I updated the code, my question is text field widget

Comment: Ideally you simply add JavaScript to the onChange handler of the PDF, so your form can be filled correctly with any viewer. Unfortunately Apple's PDFKit does not support this part of the PDF specification, you you'd need to move to a 3rd-party solution: https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/features/javascript/